# Possible bug - page not found when clicking any tag in Stack Exchange main page search results

Tags: bug, tags, search, stackexchange.com

Possible bug (probably quickly fixed?): I get "page not found" pages when clicking any tag in the Stack Exchange search results.

Example: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test

Click on a tag of any answers it displays, example: [python]

It leads to: https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python

And that page is displaying "Page Not Found" instead of a list of Python tagged questions and answers.

The root of the problem seems to be that the URL is not constructed with the question's site but with the search result (stackexchange.com) site instead, lacking the tags.

For example, https://stackexchange.com/search?q=python leads you to a result page, that shows today amongst its results the following question: *"Why is a simulation of a probability experiment off by a factor of 10?"*

If we click that title, we go on the math.stackexchange.com's site,  (*[Why is a simulation of a probability experiment off by a factor of 10?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975845/why-is-a-simulation-of-a-probability-experiment-off-by-a-factor-of-10)*), and there, clicking on "Python" rightfully leads to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python

However if we directly click the Python tag on the search result page on stackexchange.com, it tries do display: https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python (with no `math.`), and that one displays the page not found error.

Lastly, if the same page is displayed on, for example, the "Hot Questions" section: https://stackexchange.com/, clicking directly its "python" tag **would lead to the proper site** (math.stackoverflow.com) and not stay on "stackexchange.com".

I.e., direct clicking a tag is **working properly on the front page of stackexchange.com**, but **not working properly on its search result pages**.

Comment: it seems the problem is that on the search results, it doesn't use the proper url for the tag ( for ex: `stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/TAGNAME` instead of `thequestionsite/questions/tagged/TAGNAME`)